# Where can I find an exhaustive (and constantly updating) list of 5e reference and adventure books?

Tags: dnd-5e, books, online-resources

When I started D&D, I bought the PHB, MM, and DMG, of course. And not too long after that I picked up *Tyranny of Dragons* and *Out of the Abyss*. I haven't checked in for a while and I'm suddenly finding out that there's something about Drow, a *Storm King's Thunder*, and what looks like an addendum to the Monster Manual. And I'm sure that there are others I haven't spotted.

Clearly I've missed a lot.

Now, I'm not asking for the titles; the contents of that answer would be bound to change. But is there a place I can look periodically in order to ensure that I can identify new releases periodically (and find anything I may have missed)?

Comment: Does Wikipedia (or any other resource kept up to date by user edits) count? Or is this solely about, e.g., official resources listing the books?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

On the [Wizards Product Catalog page](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/catalog). Wizards tends to keep a pretty accurate catalog of their physical products, and this list can be sorted new-old, so check back there periodically and see if something crops up in front. All the books you've listed are there. (the new-old ordering seems to not be tied totally to release date — maybe the date it was announced?)

Their Product Catalog won't cover third party products, mind.

Additionally, errata and rules clarifications are published periodically in the [Sage Advice column](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles#submenu-title) on their articles site. At the time of writing, the latest version is [May 2016](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/errata-may-2016). As far as I'm aware there is not yet one single continuously-updated errata archive page.

Comment: This answer could be updated with a D&D Beyond reference