# Are there campaign setting books (released or planned) for D&D 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, campaign-settings, eberron

As a DM, I'm always searching for new and exciting settings in which to run my campaigns. I know that for previous editions, books based around settings for campaigns (most notably for me, Eberron for 3.5e) exist, however, everything I've found about the subject in the 5e books are mentions to certain settings with brief explanations of very few aspects. 5e heavily favors the Forgotten Realms setting, but I've been looking to branching into the aforementioned Eberron setting for future campaigns.

I know that Keith Baker (creator of the Eberron setting) explains in his blog how to incorporate elements from Eberron in 5e over time, however, there is hardly enough information there to adapt the entire setting.

**Are there any existing or planned 5e books dedicated solely to running a specific setting within the game, or official ways to adapt existing but non-developed settings for 5e, specifically Eberron?** (Non-developed referring to cases where unique races, classes, etc. haven't been adapted for the current edition, such as how Warforged currently contain no official rules for 5e)

Comment: I'm closing this not only because it's looking for products of a cetain type, but also because even that aside it's unmaintainable and we're not able to see the future. Even for an answer of "none", if that ever changes the answer becomes wrong; if the answer isn't "none" then it's a potentially ever-growing list. And since it's written to be time-dependent, it will stop making sense as a "forever question" as soon as anything changes. This is a topic for a researched and maintained wiki article, not a Q&A site.

Comment: Whenever D&D 5e campaign settings become more of a thing, it may be more workable to ask where a list of them can be found, [such as modelled after this question about D&D 5e adventures & modules.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/83103/1204)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't believe there are any books about adapting Eberron, there is an Unearthed Arcana edition dedicated to that exact topic [here](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/unearthed-arcana-eberron).